# Autofac.Extras.Quartz sample code crashes

Tags: autofac, quartz.net

I attempting to use Quartz with Autofac due Autofac.Extras.Quartz library. But my code crashes
It is simple but it crashes:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.Quartz;
using Quartz;
using System;

namespace Test1_netCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
            var container = builder.Build();
            IScheduler scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>(); //crashes here
            //
        }
    }
}
```

with exception:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. 
See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IScheduler (DelegateActivator), 
Services = [Quartz.IScheduler], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = Shared, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope'

Inner Exception
MissingMethodException: Method not found: "Quartz.IScheduler Quartz.ISchedulerFactory.GetScheduler()".
```

However this runs OK, when I resolve `ISchedulerFactory` and get container from it

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.Quartz;
using Quartz;
using System;

namespace Test1_netCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
            var container = builder.Build();
            //IScheduler scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
            ISchedulerFactory factory =  container.Resolve<ISchedulerFactory>();
            IScheduler scheduler = factory.GetScheduler().Result;
            //
        }
    }
}
```

What happens? I think I strongly misunderstand something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out:  Autofac.Extras.Quartz and Quartz assemblies was incompatible.
Autofac.Extras.Quartz (3.3.0) calls ISchedulerFactory method getScheduler() like this

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler())
```

(https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz/blob/26f33fa3be91a077e9edfefbc53606ab2f2ffc95/src/Autofac.Extras.Quartz/QuartzAutofacFactoryModule.cs#L89)

But in Quarts 3.0.0-alpha3 signature of this method is

```
Task<IScheduler> GetScheduler(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

(https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/bb682fe4c051b2120086170cf03ae5111832b29f/src/Quartz/ISchedulerFactory.cs#L47)

However I can use versions together with approach in second code sample in my question, just resolve `ISchedulerFactory`then `getSchduler()` from it manually.
(I really need exactly this versions of packeges because other dependencies in my project)

Comment: You should accept your answer to close the question.